# How to resize a modal page in in onic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to ionic and trying to create a simple modal. Its working fine but I'm not able to resize it, even though content part is getting resized using below css but b/g shade is still there. Can someone help me for the same?

```
 ion-content.content {
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;

    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

[image]
My modal.html

```
<ion-content padding class="sample-modal-page no-scroll">
   <h3 style="text-align:center"><strong>Are you sure you want to sign out?</strong></h3>  
  <button ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
</ion-content>
```

modal.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal',
  templateUrl: 'modal.html',
})
export class ModalPage  {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public viewCtrl : ViewController) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

  public closeModal() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }

  public logout() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting `background-color:transparent` ?

Comment: I have tried but its not helping, thanks @SaiDatta anyways

Answer (score 0):

in HTML

```
<ion-card-content>
<ion-content>
   <h3 style="text-align:center"><strong>Are you sure you want to sign out?</strong></h3>  
  <button ion-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    <button ion-button (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
</ion-content>
</ion-card-content>
```

in scss

```
page-modal{
    ion-card-content {
                padding: 0px !important;
                height: 60% !important;
                position: absolute;
                top: 20%;
                left: 18%;
                display: block;
                width: 65%; // here change your width
                height: 65%!important; // here change your width
                overflow: hidden;
                ion-content {
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mohamad rabee, I have tried this but its not helping me to get rid of the b/g. Its just changing the content area. I'm using iconic V 2.2.3 in case if it helps. From the inspect, it looks like we need to override modal-wrapper class but for some reason override to it has no effect. Any other suggestions will be appreciated.